# Saving updated user password django

Tags: django, django-users

I have a user update api that is supposed to update the user's details. I have used **set_password()** to encrypt the password and from my print statements, it seems to encrypt fine. However when I save the updated user, the password still saves as plain text. What am I missing here ?
print(user.password) gives me

```
pbkdf2_sha256$216000$26YKhuRQ4i4S$HnfbowEjappYtP7nbbMZJXcjLi13sWPpj1EqjEbUutI=
```

Yet when I return user it maintains the password as plain text.

```
class UserDetail(APIView):

def get_user(self, pk):
    try:
        return User.objects.get(pk=pk)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

def put(self, request, pk, format=None):
    user = self.get_user(pk)
    data = request.data
    new_password = data["password"]
    user.set_password(new_password)
    user.save()
    print(user.password)

    serializers = UserSerializer(user, request.data)
    if serializers.is_valid():

        serializers.save()
        return Response(serializers.data)
    else:
        return Response(serializers.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: What value do you see?

Comment: @bdbd Check the edits

Comment: That's actually expected. You can have a look [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/passwords/#how-django-stores-passwords) for more information on what that string means

Comment: So is there a way to store it as the hash instead of plain text ?